# How to restrict access to objects using detailview class

Tags: python, django, django-views

Im trying to limit the display objects to the user who created it.
Is it done using a foreign key in the object model?

Ex: 
User 1 may access object 1
User 2 may access object 2

At this moment any user can access any object just entering the correct URL to that object.

File views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import Http404
from .models import Host
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


class HostDetail(DetailView):

    model = Host

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class HostList(ListView):

    model = Host

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):

        qs = super(HostList, self).get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(perfil=self.request.user.perfil.id)
        return qs
```

File models.py

```
class Perfil(models.Model):

    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zbx_user = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    numero_hosts = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.nome

class Host(models.Model):

    host_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    templateid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tipo = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    dns = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    host_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # Relacionamento 1 pra N com Perfil
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.host_name
```

File urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from .views import HostDetail, HostList

urlpatterns = [

    # Rota para index perfis
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^host/(?P<pk>\d+)$', HostDetail.as_view(), name='HostDetail'),
    url(r'^host/$', HostList.as_view(), name='HostList'),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same approach as you use for the `ListView`. Filter the queryset using `self.request.user`.

You may also want to use `LoginRequiredMixin` on both views, so that only logged-in users can access the views.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class HostDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Host

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(HostList, self).get_queryset().filter(perfil=self.request.user.perfil_id)
        return qs

    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, it seems to resolved the problem. But im i little confused, i get rid of `get_context_data()` and it worked fine. When do i need to use it? Thanks!

Comment: I left out `get_context_data` because it wasn't relevant to the question, I wasn't saying to remove it. Overriding `get_context_data` is only useful if you want to customise the context. For an example, see the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) that adds `now` to the context. In your case, all you did was return the result of `super()`, so it is fine to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Override the dispatch() method of the DetailView class.

```
 def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Custom user permission check
    return super(HostDetail, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```