# django owner permission in detail view

Tags: django

Here is my code

```
class EnrollmentDetail(generic.DetailView):
   model = Enrollment
   template_name = 'enrollments/enrollment_detail.html'
   context_object_name = 'enrollment
```

Simple djeneric django detail view. I want only the owner of this view to can access it. Every one else i don't want go get it. I want to restrict their access. I think to raise error in that case but don't know which one. It is frustrating, because it is not complicated problem but can't solve it. I checked many posts on that matter but none of them offer slick and clean solution ( decorators, supers(), querysets etc.)

Here is my model

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
"""Defines Enrollment model"""

    doctor_name = models.ForeignKey(DoctorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    symptoms = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    received_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    room_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Thanks for help

Comment: How do you represent the owner, what is the field in your `Enrollment` model?

Comment: maybe this could help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695008/how-to-restrict-access-to-objects-using-detailview-class

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution that I figured out while I was working on my project.
Override the dispatch function in your DetailView to check whether the user trying to access the view is the owner or not. If the user is not the owner then call handle_permission_denied() method which redirects us to a certain url defined in the urlpatterns('forbidden') in our case. Make sure to import reverse_lazy and HttpResponseRedirect.

```
class CustomDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ModelName

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()

        if obj.user != request.user:
            return self.handle_permission_denied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def handle_permission_denied(self):
        redirect_url = reverse_lazy('forbidden')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can override the get_queryset in your Detailview,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: This works, but not completely, because when use which is not owner try to access it, raise the ugly gjango 404 error, which i want to handle

Answer (score -1):

Simple make a if statement and check if the logged-in user has superuser rights:

```
class EnrollmentDetail(generic.DetailView):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
       model = Enrollment
       template_name = 'enrollments/enrollment_detail.html'
       context_object_name = 'enrollment
    else:
       # redirect to page
```

Comment: This is a *class-based* view... So at the class-level, there is *no* request, etc.

Comment: yeeep, that is the problem, if it is a simple function it is easy to solve it, but this is class-based view